# Google Chrome won't update and shows error 0x800700C1. How to debug?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, updates

Google Chrome won't update, even though I suspect the error is Windows related.

Chrome isn't capable of updating itself. When going to "Help -> About Google Chrome", it shows this message:

> An error ocurred when looking for updates: The update verification failed to start (error code 3: 0x800700C1 -- system level).

[image: google chrome wont update]

I am a rather experienced developer, I don't have a Firewall or an anti-virus running, I have tried reinstalling Google Chrome but still got the error.

What can I do to further debug this?

Thanks.

Comment: 0x800700C1 is a report that something is not a valid Win32 application. You may want to run the system file checker on your system.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Just ran "sfc /scannow" on my 3 drives and got zero errors :( Anything else you might add?

Comment: You might want to try to figure out where Chrome downloads its updates to, clean that folder out, and retry the update - it may be that the download got corrupted. Beyond that, a general housecleaning couldn't be a bad thing.

Comment: Seems it might related to my low space on my Windows SSD (60gb) regarding Windows Update. Doing further research...

Comment: No luck. Changed Windows Update folder to another drive, updated Windows, still got the same error. It seems Chrome can't connect to the update server, but I couldn't find any log to further debug the issue. I ran `tracert` on `tools.google.com` and `dl.google.com` and they both reached it fine.

Comment: Tried renaming `%appdata%/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default` to `Default Backup` and running Chrome with a fresh profile, still same error.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I have moved my Users and Program Files (which Microsoft says to do at your own peril) folders to a different drive and I'm having some issues (ie: dead shortcuts, pointing partly to C, partly to E, that I have to fix manually). I have the same 0x800700C1 error and I suspect it's another related issue :( Didn't notice I was 4 versions behind the latest Chrome until now, the version I have is from when I reinstalled Windows and did the the drive change. Don't change your program files path 